# Visual Studio / TFS 2010 - How to publish all files - Web Site project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone please let me know how I can force Visual Studio 2010 to publish all files (source files included)? If this is not possible in Visual Studio, is there anyway that I could get this accomplished in TFS 2010 in my continuous build agent?

Comment: What do you mean, "Publish"? You mean publish to a target web site? What do you mean, "source files"? Which files does it not publish now?

Comment: Sorry, I meant source-code files (.vb files in my case) that I have for each web page in this website project. May be I should not have used 'Publish' - what I need to do is to have a continuous build agent in TFS that will build the project and then copy all the source code files to a destination folder, if the build succeeds.

Comment: How does this differ from what the default build does?

Comment: Default build is not "outputting" the source code (.vb) files. Is there a way that I could force it to?

Comment: No it wouldn't normally do that. Google VS2010 After Build Action, might get you there.

Comment: Why do you want the source files copied? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Suppose you publish them to IIS, don't forget to chnage your settings on RequestFiltering if you want those files to get served...

Comment: Unfortunately, we always had the source code deployed to the production servers - this is how it works at my job. This has been a manual process till now, I'm trying to make this automated - so that the files are at least pulled from TFS and copied to the servers.

Comment: What happens to your web site if you don't deploy the sources?

Answer (score 0):

in source control folder u can set the (change sets , check in , and check out) from this u can map the all source code in your company locally . can share file , codes and things related o ur work.
vote up if it help!